# Why this composite function starts behaving like a different function for specific values of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let
$$f(x) = \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \right)^2$$
Composing it with itself yields:
$$(f \circ f)(x)= \frac{ \left( 1-\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sqrt{x})^2}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}} \right)^2}{\left( 1+\sqrt{\frac{(1-\sqrt{x})^2}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}} \right)^2}$$

Doing some algebraic manipulations:
$$(f \circ f)(x)= \frac{ \left( 1-\frac{\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{x})^2}}{\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}} \right)^2}{\left( 1+\frac{\sqrt{(1-\sqrt{x})^2}}{\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}} \right)^2}$$

$$= \frac{ \left( 1-\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \right)^2}{\left( 1+\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}} \right)^2}$$

$$= \left( \frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{x}-1+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1+\sqrt{x} + 1 -\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}} \right)^2$$

$$= \left( \frac{\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{x}}} \right)^2$$

$$= \frac{\frac{4x}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}}{\frac{4}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}}$$

Multiplying by $\frac{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}{(1+\sqrt{x})^2}$:
$$= \frac{4x}{4}$$
$$= x$$

So $(f \circ f)(x) = x$ and I can see that this holds for every $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$.

But if $x > 1$ then the composite starts behaving like $$(f \circ f)(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Why does it behave like if that if doing the algebraic manipulation always yields $(f \circ f)(x) = x$. Did I make a mistake somewhere? Or there is a property that I'm not looking at?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first step seems to have skipped many in between, because it does not resemble f(f(x)) at all.

Comment: For $u<0$, you should simplify $\sqrt{u^2}=|u|=-u$. Note that when $x > 1$, $\frac{1-\sqrt x}{1 + \sqrt x} < 0$, so squaring and then square rooting amounts to taking a negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments tipped me to the correct answer. Thanks specially to Sassatelli.

I didn't applied the definition $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$.

So starting from $(f \circ f)(x)$ we have:
$$\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)^2}}{1+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)^2}}\right)^2$$

Then the correct step to follow should be:
$$\left(\frac{1-\left\lvert\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right\rvert}{1+\left\lvert\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right\rvert}\right)^2$$

And after some manipulations we end with:
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}-\left\lvert 1-\sqrt{x}\right\rvert}{1+\sqrt{x}+\left\lvert 1-\sqrt{x}\right\rvert}\right)^2$$

And this is where the value of $x$ should be taken into consideration. (Note: the domain of the function is {x | x $\geq$ 0}.

For every $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$ the value of $1-\sqrt{x}$ will always be positive and the composite will be equal to $(f \circ f)(x) = x$ just like my original post.

But for every $x$ such that $x > 1$ then $1 - \sqrt{x}$ will always be negative and taking the absolute value we are left with:
$$\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x} + 1}{1+\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}-1}\right)^2$$
And then:
$$\left(\frac{2}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)^2$$
$$\frac{4}{4x}$$
And we end with:
$$\frac{1}{x}$$
Just as expected.